# ifelse() function combined with grep() function did not return the ifelse conditions

Tags: r, regex, if-statement, data-science, bioinformatics

I want to apply a function such that if the column names of `top.genes.matrix` begins with `non-tumor`, its considered a `Ctl` sample. Otherwise, its `Glioma` sample. However, the code below returns everything as `Ctl` sample. Why?

```
type <- lapply(colnames(top.genes.matrix), 
               function(x) {
                 ifelse(grep("^non-tumor", x), "Ctl", "Glioma")
                 })
label  <- as.vector(unlist(type))
```

> > dput(top.genes.matrix[1:2,1:30]) structure(list(`non-tumor_GSM97800` = c(9.7453140114e+288, 5.29888441356601e+246 ), `non-tumor_GSM97803` = c(Inf, 3.67009936848685e+220), `non-tumor_GSM97804` = c(Inf,
> > 4.2899121663437e+41), `non-tumor_GSM97805` = c(Inf, 8.40516277768061e+129 ), `non-tumor_GSM97807` = c(Inf, 5.18689446110124e+179), `non-tumor_GSM97809` = c(Inf,
> > 1.25493857651029e+245), `non-tumor_GSM97811` = c(Inf, 1.54683122103543e+213 ), `non-tumor_GSM97812` = c(Inf, 1.1835373727435e+71), `non-tumor_GSM97816` = c(Inf,
> > 7.20674433073256e+130), `non-tumor_GSM97817` = c(Inf, Inf), `non-tumor_GSM97820` = c(Inf,
> > 9.09145681001345e+174), `non-tumor_GSM97825` = c(Inf, 4.71809784114593e+281 ), `non-tumor_GSM97827` = c(Inf, 3.02115472858483e+210), `non-tumor_GSM97828` = c(Inf,
> > 1.58083541806485e+93), `non-tumor_GSM97833` = c(Inf, 2.15709053730637e+182 ), `non-tumor_GSM97834` = c(Inf, 4.12730102449738e+267), `non-tumor_GSM97840` = c(Inf,
> > 4.13431590005232e+162), `non-tumor_GSM97846` = c(Inf, 4.22577864400639e+156 ), `non-tumor_GSM97848` = c(Inf, 2.77631637353339e+211), `non-tumor_GSM97849` = c(Inf,
> > 2.24976436669632e+275), `non-tumor_GSM97850` = c(Inf, 4.07675022923096e+131 ), `non-tumor_GSM97853` = c(Inf, 3.22445392538858e+265), `non-tumor_GSM97855` = c(Inf,
> > 2.9272477355908e+244), astrocytomas_II_GSM97878 = c(6.99920231930564e+100,
> > 2.71228730528275e+21), astrocytomas_II_GSM97913 = c(4.425834769824e+194,
> > 5.12336586495199e+43), astrocytomas_II_GSM97932 = c(4.08905013671742e+108,
> > 2581896.96873512), astrocytomas_II_GSM97939 = c(9.55556376729943e+116,
> > 2.4150058542247e+56), astrocytomas_II_GSM97951 = c(Inf, 2.33290131037584e+113 ), astrocytomas_II_GSM97957 = c(3.32525456071435e+76, 2.03569771781862e+49 ),
> > astrocytomas_II_GSM97972 = c(43317043134214.2, 500918273.092454 )),
> > row.names = c("219752_at", "240512_x_at"), class = "data.frame")
>
> > label   [1] "Ctl" "Ctl" "Ctl" "Ctl" "Ctl" "Ctl" "Ctl" "Ctl" "Ctl" "Ctl" "Ctl" "Ctl"  [13] "Ctl" "Ctl" "Ctl" "Ctl" "Ctl" "Ctl" "Ctl"
> > "Ctl" "Ctl" "Ctl" "Ctl" "Ctl"  [25] "Ctl" "Ctl" "Ctl" "Ctl" "Ctl"
> > "Ctl" "Ctl" "Ctl" "Ctl" "Ctl" "Ctl" "Ctl"  [37] "Ctl" "Ctl" "Ctl"
> > "Ctl" "Ctl" "Ctl" "Ctl" "Ctl" "Ctl" "Ctl" "Ctl" "Ctl"  [49] "Ctl"
> > "Ctl" "Ctl" "Ctl" "Ctl" "Ctl" "Ctl" "Ctl" "Ctl" "Ctl" "Ctl" "Ctl"
> > [61] "Ctl" "Ctl" "Ctl" "Ctl" "Ctl" "Ctl" "Ctl" "Ctl" "Ctl" "Ctl" "Ctl"
> > "Ctl"  [73] "Ctl" "Ctl" "Ctl" "Ctl" "Ctl" "Ctl" "Ctl" "Ctl" "Ctl"
> > "Ctl" "Ctl" "Ctl"  [85] "Ctl" "Ctl" "Ctl" "Ctl" "Ctl" "Ctl" "Ctl"
> > "Ctl" "Ctl" "Ctl" "Ctl" "Ctl"  [97] "Ctl" "Ctl" "Ctl" "Ctl" "Ctl"
> > "Ctl" "Ctl" "Ctl" "Ctl" "Ctl" "Ctl" "Ctl" [109] "Ctl" "Ctl" "Ctl"
> > "Ctl" "Ctl" "Ctl" "Ctl" "Ctl" "Ctl" "Ctl" "Ctl" "Ctl" [121] "Ctl"
> > "Ctl" "Ctl" "Ctl" "Ctl" "Ctl" "Ctl" "Ctl" "Ctl" "Ctl" "Ctl" "Ctl"
> > [133] "Ctl" "Ctl" "Ctl" "Ctl" "Ctl" "Ctl" "Ctl" "Ctl" "Ctl" "Ctl"
> > "Ctl" "Ctl" [145] "Ctl" "Ctl" "Ctl" "Ctl" "Ctl" "Ctl" "Ctl" "Ctl"
> > "Ctl" "Ctl" "Ctl" "Ctl" [157] "Ctl" "Ctl" "Ctl" "Ctl" "Ctl" "Ctl"
> > "Ctl" "Ctl" "Ctl" "Ctl" "Ctl" "Ctl" [169] "Ctl" "Ctl" "Ctl" "Ctl"
> > "Ctl" "Ctl" "Ctl" "Ctl" "Ctl" "Ctl" "Ctl"

Comment: From what your sample data seems to be showing, most of the columns start with `non-tumor`.  Why would not expect `Ctl` as the output then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`grep` returns only the matching position where as `grepl` returns the logical expression which you need. You can try it with more simpler way like this:

```
label <- ifelse(grepl("^non-tumor", colnames(top.genes.matrix)), "Ctl", "Glioma")
```